# Scroll Children (AG-Grids) from main Window

Tags: javascript, scroll, parent-child, ag-grid, horizontal-scrolling

**Goal:**

Vertically Scroll multiple tables (AG-Grid) with a "global" scroll-bar on the main window.

**Problem:**

I have 4 child elements (AG-Grid Tables) within a Window, these children can be up to 3 times the with of the main Window. 
Now the children would need to be scrolled separately and a scroll bar would be displayed in the rather slim child elements.

The goal is to display a horizontal scrollbar on the main window itself (if the children need scrolling), and this main scrollbar scrolls one of the child windows (AG-Grid offers the functionality to synchronize the scrolling of one table to another).

All 4 children always have the same width as the width is determined by the columns shown within the AG-Grid tables.

The application is written in React using AG-Grid for displaying/virtualizing these tables. So if someone has a solution specific to AG-Grid this would still be helpful.

Thanks for any input!

**Edit for clarity:** It is already possible to scroll the grids separately / the second thing working is to give the window the full with and scroll the window itself instead of the grids (This is unfortunately not a solution as the first column of the grid should be pinned to the left side of the screen so rows can still be identified when scrolled to the right)

Edit: Screenshot for clarity 
[image]

Comment: May you please share [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a shreenshot?

Comment: Added a screenshot for clarity. 

The idea is that the bottom Scrollbar controls all grids (where the first column stays pinned and is not scrolling horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to combine this two features [column pinning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pinning/#example-column-pinning) and [aligned grids](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/#example-aligned-grids). I don't know if they work together.

Comment: Both is already applied. Grids are now scrollable between them, meaning if one of them is scrolled the others are as well. Pinned columns working as well. 

The main issue is that the scrollbar on the window itsellf (around the window) should scroll all the Tables. 

I now work around it by adding a fake table to the bottom with invisible header and rows to scroll the other tables. (Which is technically correct, but prone to become a problem at one point).